# How to make AWS Logs Insights automatically discover fields for Transit Gateway Flow logs?

Tags: amazon-web-services, logging, amazon-cloudwatchlogs

I have a query I'm using in AWS Cloudwatch Log Insights to filter on IP addresses. I'm using the Transit Gateway Flow Logs as my source. Does anyone know a way to improve this query so I don't have to parse out the @message manually?

```
fields @timestamp
| parse @message "* * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * *" as version,resourceType,accountId,tgwId,tgwAttachmentId,tgwSrcVpcAccountId,tgwDstVpcAccountId,tgwSrcVpcId,tgwDstVpcId,tgwSrcId,tgwDstSubnetId,tgwSrcEni,tgwDstEni,tgwSrcAzId,tgwDstAzId,tgwPairAttachmentId,srcAddr,dstAddr,srcPort,dstPort,protocol,packets,bytes,start,end,logStatus,type,packetsLostNoRoute,packetsLostBlackhole,packetsLostMtuExceeded,packetsLostTtlExpired,tcpFlags,region,flowDirection,pktSrcAwsService,pktDstAwsService
| filter isIpv4InSubnet(srcAddr, "1.1.1.0/24")
```

The query works as is, but the `@message` field has to be manually parsed as you can see from the excerpt above. I'm trying to eliminate the parse line or to simplify it somehow.  If this was a VPC log, the fields would be auto discovered and I would have no need to parse.

Answer (score 0):

According to the [AWS Docs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudWatch/latest/logs/CWL_AnalyzeLogData-discoverable-fields.html) the fields are discovered automatically, so there is no need to parse them out. The field names are:

> @timestamp, @logStream, @message, accountId, endTime, interfaceId, logStatus, startTime, version, action, bytes, dstAddr, dstPort, packets, protocol, srcAddr, srcPort

Comment: Note that VPC flow logs != TGW flow logs. Therefore the fields are certainly different, not sure if they can be auto discovered.

Comment: True, I did overlook that this are TGW Flow Logs. According to Docs they are not auto discovered (yet?).

Comment: Or the docs could be outdated or log insights could simply be "smart", I would not be sure...

Comment: @luk2302 I don't believe the docs to be outdated. if this was a vpc log i wouldn't have to do this, but the TGW logs have the message included in them, yet this parse is the only way I can figure out to filter on the fields in message?!?